# Pointer becomes NULL immediately

Tags: c++

I have the following LLVM code. The strange thing is that the `si` variable of type `StoreInst` becomes null(0) immediately after it is allocated with new instruction outside the if block, whereas I have declared it at an outer scope. What is going on here?

```
        Value *OldVal = NULL;
        StoreInst* si = NULL;

        if ( ... )
        {
            if ( ... )
            {
                ....

                if ( ... )
                {
                    ...
                    StoreInst* si = new StoreInst(...);
                    errs() << "si = " << si << "\n"; // Get some address here
                }
                errs() << "-->SI = " << si << "\n"; // Here I get NULL, why?
            }
            ...
        }
```

I get an output like this,

```
si = 0x1822ba0
-->SI = 0x0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StoreInst* si = new StoreInst(...);` - You hidden the previos name `si` here

When the scope is ended `}` - you see the value of another pointer

Here is an example of what you did:

```
int val = 0; //first val
{
    int val = 10; //other val (let's call it second)
    cout << val; //second val
} // second val is destroyed here
cout << val; //first val
```

I've used `int` in the example for simplicity. Actually it can be any type